# View Installed Apps on particular Device on play.google.com

Tags: google-play-store

Before the redesign of [play.google.com](https://play.google.com/) (the website, not the Android app), there was a way of viewing what apps where installed on a device of yours and what apps where in your library but not installed on the specific device.

After the redesign I have not been able to find this option to view your apps library broken down as such.

Is it still possible to view your apps library as two lists, one list of apps installed on a particular device and another of apps not installer on that device?

Comment: It looks like they launched some incomplete build. I hope the old functionality will be "restored" (rather re-added) soon, and it looks like they are still doing some work at it. Though I have to admit that most of their recent "updates" where rather "downgrades" when it comes to functionality :(

Comment: @Izzy yes I would have to agree their recent updates have been aesthetically nice mostly but yet they remove features each time it seems.

Comment: I even have to disagree on the "aestetically nice". The tiles make it difficult to handle (especially on smaller screens), text gets cut (sometimes even unreadable). Searches limited to 48 results, which makes research impossible. I cannot see any added value there, sorry, and for most things switched to [AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/) therefore. As they also handle updates etc. when using their client (AppBrain ist just an alternative front-end to Google Play), it might be possible you can find an answer that way (I did not check this recently).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Luckily, this is possible again:

- while logged in with your Google account, visit [Playstore's your apps page](https://play.google.com/apps) (you can also reach this from your [Google Dashboard](https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard), scrolling to *Play Store*, and hit the "view apps" link)
- at the top of the page, you should see a "link" labeled "all apps". That's a drop-down, push it
- now select the device you want to see the apps for.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot of the described drop-down (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only see "Alle Apps", "Familienmediathek", "Abos" (translated: all apps / family media library / subscriptions) as of the time writing this comment.

Comment: @ComFreek well, all things Google are subject to change continually :( What I wrote was 3 years ago.